# Share data via QEMU and NFS with Mac host (OSX Catalina) and Linux Guest (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: linux, mac-osx, kvm-virtualization, nfs, qemu

## Story so far

We recently migrated from Linux laptops to Macbook Pro laptops (company IT no longer supports native Linux laptops with VPN, so it's all Macbook/OSX devices for us). However, all of our development requires the use of Ubuntu and Debian, so we're running everything in virtual machines. Our plan is to use QEMU ([with the appropriate hardware acceleration via `hvf`](https://opensource.com/article/20/9/try-linux-mac)) to easily spin up VMs on-demand. We are able to successfully launch our VMs via something like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -m 4096 \
  -smp 4\
  -accel hvf \
  -show-cursor \
  -drive file=/public/my_os_disk.qcow2,if=virtio \
  -net user,hostfwd=tcp::8022-:22 \
  -net nic
```

This starts up our VM (Ubuntu) instance with 4GB of RAM, 4 cores, hardware acceleration, and allows us to `ssh` into the VM (port 22 from the VM's perspective) via `ssh -p8022 username@localhost`.

## Question

How can we setup an NFS server on the Linux guest so that our Mac/OSX host can share files? If the host were also Linux, we could use `virtfs` like we used to, but it seems our solution must involve networking. We've setup NFS server on the Ubuntu VM (using common articles, [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo), 2). We then setup the QEMU launcher script to enable the [NFS ports](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-scale/5.1.0?topic=firewall-recommendations-protocol-access) (i.e. 111, 2049), like so:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
  -m 4096 \
  -smp 4\
  -accel hvf \
  -show-cursor \
  -drive file=/public/my_os_disk.qcow2,if=virtio \
  -net user,hostfwd=tcp::8022-:22,hostfwd=tcp::2049-:2049,hostfwd=tcp::111-:111 \
  -net nic
```

On the Mac host (or OSX host), we attempt to mount the NFS share (assuming the Linux guest is exporting the `/export_from_linux` path on the the `10.0.100.0/24` subnet) via:

```
mount -t nfs localhost:/export_from_linux  /my_mac_mount_path
```

However, this just hangs indefinitely.

**What is the best way to (preferably using NFS) establish a means of sharing files between a Mac/OSX host, and a Linux/Ubuntu guest running in QEMU?**

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to hostfwd 111, just 2049, or alternatively you can use a map from 8049 to 2049; *as 2049 might be occupied on the macOS system*.

So at minimum, you will need to have QEMU create a mapping for the alternate NFS port:

```
-netdev user,hostfwd=tcp::8049-:2049
```

Now you can mount NFS on port 8049 on the macOS side; say, to a Debian NFSv4 server:

```
sudo mount -o port=8049,vers=4,resvport -t nfs 127.0.0.1:/export_from_linux /my_mac_mount_path
```

Note that we are using an option to enforce `vers=4` on the macOS side (and you should be running an NSFv4 compatible server on the Linux side; i.e. Debian 11's nfs-kernel-server.

BUT the main key here is the `resvport` setting. For whatever reason, macOS would not mount without this setting.